# how to install OpenStack on Ubuntu in 2022

Tags: openstack, devstack

On youtube there are many guides that show how to install openstack on ubuntu I have tried them and they seem not to work

For example with Devstack I fail every time the installation with .Stack.sh, with MicroStack I fail the initialization

I can't install OpenStack in any way!

could somebody help me?

Comment: You'll need to add some information about what is failing for us to be able to help you, e.g. error messages, Ubuntu version, OpenStack version etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I managed it obviously I had to install Ubuntu on a Physical Machine, with Microstack, if I tried to install Microstack on a virtual machine it would fail for sure, in my opinion I don't think it is possible to run openstack on a virtual machine!

Comment: I actually run OpenStack using devstack on a virtual machine. I pretty much just follow the following steps. Btw important to use Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04.
https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/install-openstack-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed openstack from various different ways but for me installing through Devstack is the easiest and the most convenient way to do it.

Let me share the installation steps that I use:

Firstly few prerequisites:

- A fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation (Ubuntu 18.04 Works)
- 8 GB RAM (4 GB RAM works)
- 4 vCPUs (2 vCPUs works)
- Hard disk capacity of 20 GB (min 10 GB)

Step 1 : `apt update -y && apt upgrade -y`

Step 2: Create Stack user:

```
sudo adduser -s /bin/bash -d /opt/stack -m stack
echo "stack ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/stack
su - stack
```

Step 3:

```
git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
cd devstack
```

Step 4: Create devstack configuration file

```
vim local.conf
```

Paste this:

```
[[local|localrc]]

# Password for KeyStone, Database, RabbitMQ and Service
ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

# Host IP - get your Server/VM IP address from ip addr command
HOST_IP=0.0.0.0
```

Step 5: **`./stack.sh`**

The setup will take about 10-15 minutes depending upon your system. Once installation is complete you can access the dashboard using `https://your-ip/dashboard`

*Note:* Incase the stack.sh fails make sure to use `./unstack` and `./clean.sh` before you use stack.sh again.

Comment: Thank you very much !, Devstack worked for me !!, only on version 20.04 on Ubuntu, on this version I was lucky.

Both Devstack and Microstack only worked for me on this version, if I would try on other versions I would not be able to install OpenStack.

These are the steps I used too, Installation takes me more than 15 minutes.
About an hour and a half

Comment: In my opinion, the only way to run OpenStack Services on a Windows platform is to create a virtual machine with Ubuntu Server 20.04 and run the commands above, is that it?

Comment: I am glad that it has worked for you. Installation time depends on your system so yeah maybe it took a lot longer for you than it did for me.

Comment: What about re-starting step one need to complete after VM restart? should I run again ./stack.sh ?